# Link renders the first partial match in React Route v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

Using codes below, it only linked to ListComponent when i want to linked to DetailsComponent. If change

```
Details: route('data/tower/list/item'),
```

to

```
Details: route('data/tower/item'),
```

it can link to DetailsComponent.I don't why and how to fix it ?

```
const EnumRouter = {
    ...
    List: route('data/tower/list'),
    Details: route('data/tower/list/item'),
};

<Switch>
    ...
    //ListComponent
    <MainLayout path={EnumRouter.List} component={List} />
    //DetailsComponent
    <MainLayout path={EnumRouter.Details} component={Details} />
   ...
</Switch>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That happens because

1. You are making use of Switch Component, which renders the first route that matches, which is ofCourse correct thing to do.
2. You have your List Route as `'data/tower/list'` and your Details Route as `'data/tower/list/item'`, however Router doesn't look for a complete match, In your case `'data/tower/list'` matches(although not completely but with the initial part) the Details Route and hence even when you try to Route to Details, it routes to List component.

The solution is to make use of the `exact` attribute for the Route.

From the **[Documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/exact-bool)**:

**exact: bool**

When true, will only match if the path matches the `location.pathname` exactly.

```
**path**    **location.pathname**   **exact**   **matches?**

/one            /one/two              true         no
/one            /one/two              false        yes
```

Change the code to

```
<Switch>
    ...
    //ListComponent
    <MainLayout exact path={EnumRouter.List} component={List} />
    //DetailsComponent
    <MainLayout path={EnumRouter.Details} component={Details} />
   ...
</Switch>
```